# ActionScript 2 XML Problem

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

The XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rtv version="1" time="1290508867">
  <genres>
    <genre en="Action">1</genre>
    <genre en="Adventure">2</genre>
    <genre en="Animation">3</genre>
    <genre en="Comedy">4</genre>
    <genre en="Crime">5</genre>

    <genre en="Disaster">6</genre>
    <genre en="Documentary">7</genre>
    <genre en="Drama">8</genre>
    <genre en="Eastern">9</genre>
    <genre en="Erotic">10</genre>
    <genre en="Family">11</genre>

    <genre en="Fan Film">12</genre>
    <genre en="Fantasy">13</genre>
    <genre en="Film Noir">14</genre>
    <genre en="History">15</genre>
    <genre en="Holiday">16</genre>
    <genre en="Horror">17</genre>

    <genre en="Indie">18</genre>
    <genre en="Music">19</genre>
    <genre en="Musical">20</genre>
    <genre en="Mystery">21</genre>
    <genre en="Neo-noir">22</genre>
    <genre en="Road Movie">23</genre>

    <genre en="Romance">24</genre>
    <genre en="Science Fiction">25</genre>
    <genre en="Short">26</genre>
    <genre en="Sport">27</genre>
    <genre en="Sporting Event">28</genre>
    <genre en="Sports Film">29</genre>

    <genre en="Suspense">30</genre>
    <genre en="Thriller">31</genre>
    <genre en="War">32</genre>
    <genre en="Western">33</genre>
    <genre en="Action and Adventure">34</genre>
    <genre en="Reality">35</genre>

    <genre en="Mini-Series">36</genre>
  </genres>
</rtv>
```

The Code

```
var genresbyID;
var gxml = new XML();
gxml.ignoreWhite = true;
gxml.load(apipath+"?section=genres");
gxml.onLoad = function(success:Boolean):Void {
    var g = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(this.firstChild, "/rtv/genres/genre");
    for(i=0;i<g.length;i++)
    {
        var s = ' '+g[i].attributes.en;
        genresbyID[g[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue*1] = s;
    }
    trace('|'+genresbyID[1]);
};
```

expected output:

```
Action
```

actual output:

```
(nothing)
```

I'm really stuck on this one. :(
Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

There are several improvements you can do to your code, but as to not confuse the issue I will ignore those. You need to initialize genresbyID to an Array or Object. It looks like Array will work for you.

```
var genresbyID:Array = new Array();
```